# OpenAPI 3.0 - how to merge/unwrap items from one array into another?

Tags: arrays, swagger, openapi

In OpenAPI 3.0, if I have two components that are arrays of similar types like so:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    AquaticMammals:
      type: array
      items:
        anyOf:
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Dolphin'
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Otter'
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Seal'
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Beaver'
    LandMammals:
      type: array
      items:
        anyOf:
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Elephant'
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Bear'
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Monkey'
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Camel'
```

Is there a nice way to create an array containing all elements from both lists without having to maintain a copy of both lists in a third component?

I've tried a few variations on `anyOf` and `allOf` including this, but I end up with an array of arrays rather than a single array containing the elements of both arrays.

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    Mammals:
      type: array
      items:
        anyOf:
          - allOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/AquaticMammals'
          - allOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/LandMammalsMammals'
```

Essentially what I'm looking for is an OpenAPI 3.0 equivalent of a javascript spread operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    Mammals:
      type: array
      items:
        anyOf:
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/AquaticMammals/items'
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/LandMammals/items'
```

Alternatively, you can create named schemas for the initial `anyOf` lists, this will make referencing a bit easier.

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    AquaticMammal:
      anyOf:
       - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Dolphin'
       - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Otter'
       - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Seal'
       - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Beaver'
    AquaticMammals:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/AquaticMammal'

    LandMammal:
      anyOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Elephant'
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Bear'
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Monkey'
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Camel'
    LandMammals:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/LandMammal'

    Mammals:
      type: array
      items:
        anyOf:
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/AquaticMammal'
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/LandMammal'
```